# the class extended Jobs running background blocks request/response in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, jobs, playframework-1.x, job-scheduling

I'm new at using play framework and I need to have a piece of code running everyday without effecting request/response cycle of play! I did this in `Job` class of play and the `Job` running time is little more than half hour. After running my play app, then I recognized that while `Job` is running play doesn't accept any request. The methods in my controller responds after `Job` finish its task. So it means it is blocking them. I am waiting for your advice.

```
import parser.Parser;
import parser.ProductModel;
import play.jobs.Every;
import play.jobs.Job;
import play.jobs.OnApplicationStart;

@OnApplicationStart
@Every("24h")
public class ParserJob extends Job {
//private Parser parser=new Parser();
@Override
public void doJob() throws Exception {
    Parser parser=new Parser();
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        parser.firsatBuFirsat("http://www.firsatbufirsat.com/");
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("TIME : "+(finish-start)/1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@OnApplicationStart` to `OnApplicationStart(async = true)`